# How to perform a row-wise operation against each column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframes:

```py
> df1
         returns
symbol
A       3
AA      6
AAL     6
AAP     1
AAPL    4

> df2

symbol      ^GSPC    ^IXIC   ^RUT
returns         1        2      3
```

`df1` has a shape of `(N x 1)` and `df2` has a shape of `(1 x M)`. How can I perform an operation, say, subtraction, such that the output dataframe looks like:

```py
> output = perform_sub(df1, df2)

           ^GSPC      ^IXIC     ^RUT
symbol
A          3 - 1      3 - 2    3 - 3
AA         6 - 1      6 - 2    6 - 3
AAL        6 - 1      6 - 2    6 - 3
AAP        1 - 1      1 - 2    1 - 3
AAPL       4 - 1      4 - 2    4 - 3
```

NOTE: I have tried using `df1.sub(df2)` and all variations using `.squeeze()`, however, it always ends up in a `NaN` filled output. I think it has something to do with the indices of each `df`.

EDIT: One possible way to arrive at the solution was converting the dataframes to numpy and then recasting to a dataframe, but I am hoping for a more `pandas` solution.

```py
output = pd.DataFrame(df1.to_numpy() - df2.to_numpy(), index=df1.index, columns=df2.columns)
```

Comment: using numpy here is the way to go

Comment: Or you can use [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) together with [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: @DannyVarod Can you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of pandas' love of indices, you're not going to get out of using numpy at some point here without a lot more complication.

Given:

```
>>> df1
        returns
symbol
A             3
AA            6
AAL           6
AAP           1
AAPL          4
>>> df2
         ^GSPC  ^IXIC  ^RUT
symbol
returns      1      2     3
```

Your method can be used to add the columns to df1 as well:

```
>>> df1[df2.columns] = df1.to_numpy() - df2.to_numpy()
>>> df1
        returns  ^GSPC  ^IXIC  ^RUT
symbol
A             3      2      1     0
AA            6      5      4     3
AAL           6      5      4     3
AAP           1      0     -1    -2
AAPL          4      3      2     1
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. The column approach is what I went with eventually anyways!